# consul query all service nodes in one request

Tags: consul

https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/http/catalog.html

> /v1/catalog/services: Lists the nodes in a given service

I have lot of services, have to query consul for the nodes for each of them .. THUS This is called multiple times

> /v1/catalog/service/ : Nodes for the service

need a http api to get all the services in just one requests , something like

> /v1/catalog/servicesNodes : Nodes for each service

```
{
 "service1":[{Node":"2e6c1dbe173f","Address":"172.17.42.1",
             "ServiceID":"aa:80", "ServiceName":"aaww",...},{}],
 "service2":[{Node":"2e6c1dbe173ee","Address":"172.17.42.1",
             "ServiceID":"aaqq:80", "ServiceName":"aaqqww",...},{}],

}
```

Comment: I think no such http api is exposed by current consul implementation. But if you use spring-cloud-consul-starter-all library bundle then can find many such kind of implementations out there. Specially have a look over classes ConsulDiscoveryClient & ConsulClient.

Comment: doesn't make sense to use spring-cloud-consul-starter-all ,, internally if consul is not providing those api ..